# If $E[|X_n|] = O(n)$ is $E[|X_n|^2] = O(n^2)$?

Tags: probability, random-variable, expected-value, asymptotics

Let $X_n$ be a random variable that depends on $n$ and suppose $E[|X_n|] = O(n)$. Then can we say $E[|X_n|^2] = O(n^2)$? If it doesn't hold in general, are there particular interesting cases where it does hold?

Comment: Let $X_n/n$ have a Student $t_2$ distribution. The problem in this case is that $E[|X_n|^2]=\infty$ for all $n.$ The take-home lesson is that the expectation of $|X|$ tells you little about the expectation of higher powers of $|X|.$ It's unclear what you might mean by "particular interesting cases:" almost by definition, these would be all sequences of random variables that satisfy all your criteria -- but so what?